# python requests from usnews.com timing out other websites work fine

Tags: python, python-requests

```
url = "https://www.usnews.com"
page = requests.get(url, timeout = 5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
```

`requests` from `usnews.com` is not working properly. The code runs forever or times out after five seconds as instructed. I have tried using other websites which work perfectly fine (wikipedia.org, google.com).

Comment: The site might be blocked by a firewall or any number of other reasons.

Comment: have a look at robots.txt file (https://www.usnews.com/robots.txt). this file generally describes the permissions for bot access.

Answer (score 1):

They are using a special protection against web scrapers like you. Whenever you go to a website, your web browser sends a special piece of data called a `User-Agent`. It tells the website what type of browser you are using and if you are on a phone or computer. By default, the `requests` module doesn't do this.

You can set your own `User-Agent` pretty easily. Using your website as an example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36"}

url = "https://www.usnews.com"
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
```

This code tells the website that we are an actual person and not a bot.

You can learn more about User Agents here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like selenium this code is similar to selenium but a bit user friendly

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import re
#from fake_useragent import UserAgent
#create the session
#ua = UserAgent()
session = HTMLSession()

#define our URL
url = "https://www.usnews.com"

#use the session to get the data
r = session.get(url)

#Render the page, up the number on scrolldown to page down multiple times on a page
r.html.render(sleep=1,timeout = 30, keep_page=True, scrolldown=1)

print(r.text)
```

this code mimics a real search engine and should bypass the bot detection